# hook_nodeapi recusrion hell (calling node_save during update op)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-hooks

I'm developing a site (D6) that runs geocode lookups every time a node is inserted or updated, the node has an address textfield and hidden fields for a lat/lng pair, and during hook_nodeapi I want to call this geocoding function.

The issue is that the geocoder needs to save this new latlng pair to the node, which in turn calls hook_nodeapi, and thus my recursion issue has been spawned.

Whats the best method for avoiding this headache?

Answer (score 0):

If you are completly sure, that you cannot change geocoder behavior, you can use simple workaround:

```
static $geocoded_nodes = array();

if (!$geocoded_nodes[$node->nid]) {
   $geocoded_nodes[$node->nid] = TRUE;
   call_geocoder_stuff().
}
```

As alternative, You can also can try to add non used field to node passed to geocoder logic.

```
if (!isset($node->geocoding_done)) {
   $node->geocoding_done = TRUE;
   call_geocoder_stuff($node).
}
```

I'm not sure if this field won't be discarded on node_save logic, but this should work.